# SQL compares the value of 2 columns and select the column with max value row-by-row

Tags: sql

I have table something like:

| GROUP | NAME | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | DEF | 4 | 4 |
| 50 | XYZ | 6 | 6 |
| 50 | QWE | 6 | 7 |
| 100 | XYZ | 26 | 2 |
| 100 | QWE | 26 | 2 |

What I would like to do is to groupby group and select the name with highest value_1. If their value_1 are the same, compare and select the max with value_2. If they're still the same, select the first one.
The output will be something like:

| GROUP | NAME | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DEF | 4 | 4 |
| 50 | QWE | 6 | 7 |
| 100 | XYZ | 26 | 2 |

The challenge for me here is I don't know how many categories in NAME so a simple case when is not working. Thanks for help

Comment: Please format your example data as tables so that it is readable i.e. 1st row is column headers, subsequent rows are data

Comment: Hi, you don't need to use case there. You should go with some window functions most likely, and maybe with some CTE. It would be easier to suggest something if you'd provide what db you use and some scripts like in https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And what you mean by "If they're still the same, select the first one."?

Comment: Relational tables have no concept of record order - so "select the first one" could return a different value every time you run your query. If you want to return a specific value then you need to define the logic to identify that value e.g. lowest value, highest value, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. Actually I just learn SQL, so super new here. Select the first one means select the first row if both value_1 and value_2 between 2 names are equal. You see in the example XYZ, and QWR  in group 100 are identical, so XYZ is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to solve the bulk of your problem:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by value1 desc, value2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The one caveat is the condition:

> If they're still the same, select the first one.

SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi-) sets.  There is no "first" one unless a column specifies the ordering.  The best you can do is choose an arbitrary value when all the other values are the same.

That said, you might have another column that has an ordering.  If so, add that as a third key to the `order by`.

Comment: Great help. Thank you very much.